# Error:XML version "2.0" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have tried updating my app to newer version to publish it to google play store, however when I change the version and generate the signed APK I get this error:
Error:XML version "2.0" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported.
I have absolutely no idea what could be causing it. Can anyone point me in the right direction or at least tell me where I should find what's wrong??

Answer (score 2):

Open your manifest file and change xml version from 2.0 to 1.0. It should run properly now.

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem before, so the solution is here.

Try to increase your versionCode and change your versionName in gradle file only.

Do not increase the version in manifest file.

> versionCode 2 // an example (if the previous one was 1)
>
> versionName 1.1 // an example (if the previous one was 1.0)